# How to find the solution coset x in a equation involving cosets?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible to kindly tell me the steps necessary to find $\overline{x}$ for the following equation?

$$
\overline{3}\overline{x} = \overline{2} \text{ in } \mathbb{Z}_5 \text{ where } \mathbb{Z}_5 \text{ is quotient ring } \mathbb{Z} / \langle 5 \rangle \text{ and } \overline{3}, \overline{x} \text{ and } \overline{2} \text{ are element cosets of } \mathbb{Z}_5
$$

The answer is given: $\overline{x} = \overline{4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to find some $x$ satisfying the following congruence:

$$3x\equiv 2\operatorname{mod}5$$

In other words, we need $3x-2$ to be divisible by $5$, so we have $3x-2=5k$ for some integer $k$.  Solving for $x$ gives:

$$x=\frac{5k+2}{3}$$

Plug in values for $k$ until $x$ is an integer.  You will find that $k=2$ gives $x=4$.

Of course, plugging in $k=2+3m$ also gives $x=5m+4\equiv 4\operatorname{mod}5$.